# How to load up only a few variables from a structure?

Tags: matlab

So I have a structure that's 600 MB large, and it contains around 8 similar variables in it. If I load up the entire structure, it will almost overwhelm my computer's RAM, which results in very sluggish performance.

I know that I can selectively save all of the variables in a single .mat file when they aren't part of a structure, but I'm applying several functions to each of the variables, and putting the variables in as structures really helps reduce the amount of code I have to write.

Comment: Did you try the `matfile`-command instead of `load`/`save`? "Access and change variables directly in MAT-files, without loading into memory"

Comment: Hmm - good idea. I just looked into it. But it says "matfile does not support indexing into Fields of structure arrays"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load a field of struct into a variable (MATLAB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260371/load-a-field-of-struct-into-a-variable-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7260665/2816823) by Mansoor Siddiqui. If you aren't using MATLAB 7 or higher there is no way of doing this. You can certainly load in the variable and immediately clear it after extracting the fields you want.